# Console output to email in Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, scripting, smtp

I am writing a powershell script for a monthly maintenance process. In order to track it I am using a try catch block that will send an email when it succeeds or fails. To do this I am using smtp. I am wondering how to write the console output to the email. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Having trouble getting started.

Thank you in advance.

This is what I recently tried but it didn't work:

```
catch {

$smtpServer = "example"
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg.From = "example"
$msg.To.Add("example")
$msg.Subject = "MONTHLY MAINTENANCE FAILED!"
$msg.Body= Write-Error ("Monthly maintenance failed! Please investigate." + $_)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$msg.Dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What "Didn't work"?

SUGGESTION:

1) Write a sample script that deliberately triggers the error

2) Make sure you're successfully capturing the error text you want (you should be able to get it from `$_`, like you're doing)

3) Make sure your e-mail parameters are correct

4) Divide and conquer: Powershell syntax first, E-Mail connectivity after.

My hunch is you'll need to debug your e-mail connectivity.

For example:

```
Try {
     1/0  # throw "divide by zero"
}    
Catch {
     $errmsg = "Monthly maintenance failed! Please investigate." + $_
     Write-Console $errmsg

     $smtpServer = "example"
     $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
     $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
     $msg.From = "example"
     $msg.To.Add("example")
     $msg.Subject = "MONTHLY MAINTENANCE FAILED!"
     $msg.Body= $errmsg
     $smtp.Send($msg)
     $msg.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I think using a variable as the input to $msg.Body was the trick. Ok so I have another question. Is there a way to get all the output from the console instead of just the errors?

Comment: "Get output from the console" basically means "redirect stdin".  You should be able to simply use redirect operators like `>` or `|`, depending on exactly what you want to do.  Here's an article with more details: [Understanding streams redirection and write-host in Powershell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx).